# How does `rescue $!` work?

Tags: ruby, exception

I know that the global variable `$!` holds the most recent exception object, but I am having confusion with the syntax below. Can anyone help me understand the following syntax?

```
 rescue $!
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This construct prevents exception from stopping your program and bubbling up the stack trace. It also returns that exception as a value, which can be useful.

```
a = get_me_data rescue $!
```

After this line, `a` will hold either requested data or an exception. You can then analyze that exception and act accordingly.

```
def get_me_data
  raise 'No data for you'
end

a = get_me_data rescue $!
puts "Execution carries on"

p a
# >> Execution carries on
# >> #<RuntimeError: No data for you>
```

#### More realistic example

```
lines = File.readlines(filename) rescue $!
```

You either get the lines or the error (if file doesn't exist, you don't have permissions, etc). In any case, execution doesn't stop.

Comment: Could you offer me a good books or articles which contains the Array and Hash techniques in Ruby. Where I could get more and more examples to see on Array and hashes, Ohh! missed one also strings too? Please. please... My most favorite professor!

Comment: @TheMiddleMan: ehm, what about official docs? They contain plenty of examples.

Comment: yes, you are right, but that is not sometimes more descriptive. I want to digest all those,really eager to learn. Sometimes I tried something on the `IRB` and got some data output which I might not expected, so reasons are not known to me as well. So without explanation nothing can be digest. Hope you would agree with me. And really would like to know to inform you in such a case, but I don't have any email id of yours... thus couldn't :(